# setOnClickListener picking up wrong image to next activity in onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-videoview

I am trying to show image in new activity from onBindViewHolder.  But it is picking up wrong image and setting in ImageView and sometimes same image showing while clicking all the images.  I am not sure because of loading list of files inside RecyclerView may cause this. Any point of improvement will be helpful.

GalleryFragment.java

```
package com.example.mokkajokes.ui.whatsappstatus;



public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String WHATSAPP_STATUSES_LOCATION = "/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";
private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewMediaList;
private TextView message;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
public static final String TAG = "Home";

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ws, container, false);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    mRecyclerViewMediaList = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMedia);
    message = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.message);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    mRecyclerViewMediaList.setLayoutManager(manager);
    //RecyclerViewMediaAdapter recyclerViewMediaAdapter = new RecyclerViewMediaAdapter(this.getListFiles(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()+WHATSAPP_STATUSES_LOCATION)), getActivity());
    WSAdapter recyclerViewMediaAdapter = new WSAdapter(this.getListFiles(new File("/storage/extSdCard/"+WHATSAPP_STATUSES_LOCATION)), getActivity());
    mRecyclerViewMediaList.setAdapter(recyclerViewMediaAdapter);
    recyclerViewMediaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return root;
}

private ArrayList<File> getListFiles(File parentDir)
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ext Dir " + parentDir, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files;

    files=parentDir.listFiles();

    if(files!=null)
    {
        for(File file:files)
        {
            if(file.getName().endsWith(".jpg") || file.getName().endsWith(".gif") || file.getName().endsWith(".mp4"))
            {
                if(!inFiles.contains(file))
                    inFiles.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    if(inFiles.size()>0)
        message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return inFiles;
}
}
```

WSAdapter.java

```
package com.example.mokkajokes.ui.whatsappstatus;

public class WSAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<WSAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<File> filesList;
File uploadCurrent;

public WSAdapter(ArrayList<File> uploads,Context context) {
    this.filesList = uploads;
    this.mContext =  context;
}
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.ws_image_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(inflatedView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final WSAdapter.ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    uploadCurrent = filesList.get(position);
    if (!uploadCurrent.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp4")) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uploadCurrent.getAbsolutePath());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }else{
        Uri video = Uri.parse(uploadCurrent.getAbsolutePath());
        holder.videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    }

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent go = new Intent(mContext, WSImageDetailsActivity.class);
            go.putExtra("path",uploadCurrent.getAbsolutePath());
            mContext.startActivity(go);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filesList.size();
}
public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public VideoView videoView;
    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_ws);
        videoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_view_ws);
    }
}
}
```

WSImageDetailsActivity.java

```
package com.example.mokkajokes.ui.whatsappstatus;

public class WSImageDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public TextView textViewName;
public ImageView imageView;
public String name,url;
public VideoView videoView;
Bundle extras=null;
public String path;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ws_image_details_view);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view_ws);
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view_ws);
    path = extras.getString("path");

    imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
    videoView.clearFocus();
    if(!path.endsWith(".mp4")) {
        videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
    else{
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
    }
    getIntent().removeExtra("path");
}
}
```

fragment_ws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="ui.whatsappstatus.GalleryFragment">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/title_pics" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMedia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ws_image_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_ws"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view_ws"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

ws_image_details_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_ws"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view_ws"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: possible same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331248/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-a-specific-item-onclick-in-a-recyclerview/60331478#60331478

Comment: Shall I change onclicklistener like this?

Comment: holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checkState[position]){
                    checkState[position]=false;
                }else{
                    checkState[position]=true;
                }
                Intent go = new Intent(mContext, WSImageDetailsActivity.class);
                go.putExtra("path",uploadCurrent.getAbsolutePath());
                mContext.startActivity(go);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store `File uploadCurrent` in adapter scope, it means `onClick` always get info of last view holder bind to adapter, try to move `File uploadCurrent` into `onBindViewHolder` and remove it in outer.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final WSAdapter.ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final File uploadCurrent = filesList.get(position);
    if (!uploadCurrent.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp4")) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uploadCurrent.getAbsolutePath());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }else{
        Uri video = Uri.parse(uploadCurrent.getAbsolutePath());
        holder.videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    }

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent go = new Intent(mContext, WSImageDetailsActivity.class);
            go.putExtra("path",uploadCurrent.getAbsolutePath());
            mContext.startActivity(go);
        }
    });
}
```